# Lockfile issue during Bundle install in TeamCity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, teamcity

I get bellow error while building my ruby project in TeamCity. Does it mean my TeamCity server has older version of Bundler?

```
[03:18:07][Step 1/2] Resolving dependencies...
[03:18:07][Step 1/2] Your lockfile was created by an old Bundler that left some things out.
[03:18:07][Step 1/2] You can fix this by adding the missing gems to your Gemfile, running bundle install, and then removing the gems from your Gemfile.
[03:18:07][Step 1/2] The missing gems are:
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that your local system has an older version of Bundler than the one running on TeamCity.

You should be able to resolve it locally by updating Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

then run bundle again which should update your Gemfile.lock with whatever information the TeamCity version of Bundler wants to see.

Comment: Ginty, thanks for the reply. But I am getting the error at TeamCity server; not on my local computer.

Comment: Understood, but I assume you can't change the version of Bundler running on TeamCity, so you can solved it by changing the one on your local system which seems to be out of date and which is the real root cause of the problem.